# Connecting C# Windows Form Application to Sql Server

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlexception

I'm connecting my windows form application to SQL server but I get this error "SqlException was unhandled" when I start the program.

Here is my code:

```
void ShowEmployees()
    {
        using (SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);" + "Database='SanMarDryCleaners';" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            string strEmployees = "SELECT * FROM employees;";

            SqlCommand cmdEmployees = new SqlCommand(strEmployees, Connect);

            SqlDataAdapter daEmployees = new SqlDataAdapter();

            daEmployees.SelectCommand = cmdEmployees;
            DataSet dsEmployees = new DataSet("EmployeesSet");
            daEmployees.Fill(dsEmployees);

            Connect.Open();

            dgvEmployees.DataSource = dsEmployees;
            dgvEmployees.DataMember = dsEmployees.Tables[0].TableName;
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Which [SQL database system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) are you trying to connect to? [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) as you've tagged the question or [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) as the use of [the `SqlClient` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.aspx) suggests? Also note that it appears you're trying to use the `Connect`ion with `Fill()` before it's been `Open`ed.

Comment: MySQL. I'm sorry if I'm wrong. I'm referring to this exercise:
http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/adonet/dads.htm
the exercise used Microsoft SQL Server. But how do I connect it up to MySQL? I already manually created a database and its tables same on the exercise. My problem is how do I connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggest that it can't find the SQL Server. And that makes sense because you are using a SqlConnection class which is for Microsoft SQL Server only. You have to use MySQL libary.

Download it from this site:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Then if I will change SqlConnection to MySqlConnection, it will be ok? I'm new with c# by the way.

Comment: You still have to change the code so it uses mysql connection a. Use Google to find a sample. it is not hard. let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

The error points to a problem while connecting to the server.

A `SqlConnection` is for SQL-Servers. Use a library specific to `MySQL` and a `MySqlConnection`.

See:

[Connector/Net Installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html)

[MySQL Connector/Net connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/)

Comment: I'm doing this exercise:
http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/adonet/dads.htm

I think the connection to the SQL is outdated. I've tried the "MySqlConnection" but it doesn't work. I already run the MySQL Server.

Comment: @JMTrasfiero That tutorial is written with the assumption that Microsoft's SQL Server is being used. If you want to connect to MySQL instead, then you'll have to swap out any uses of `SqlClient` classes, as they're specific to Microsoft servers.